# Android Add date to calendar

Tags: android, calendar

i converted String "Mon, 11 Feb 2013 08:00:00 CST" to date using the following code

```
java.util.Date d=null;
    try {
         d= new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z").parse("date");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How to add this date to calendar as a  beginTime and also an endTime 30minutes difference to the start time. i want to make a popup sheet to enter other details also.it should be compatable for all android versions.
can anyone helpme out in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this may not directly be the answer you want but I've recently been working with time/date manipulation and I installed the Joda-time API. It's a lot easier to control.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/